# How to avoid the error "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" in C# while reading excel sheet

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, list, null

I'm trying to insert excel sheet data into a DB using Lists.in. In the excel data I have some empty cells. Because of the empty cells I am getting errors like `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`. How can I solve this error? Thanks.

**I tried this code:**

```
 public object verify(object k)
 {
       try
       {
            if (range.Cells[rCnt, 3] == null)
            {
                  return  range.Cells[rCnt, 3].value="null";
            }
       }
       catch
       {
            return k;
       }

 }
```

but it shows an error at method name.

Comment: put a try catch and avoid it...

Comment: Have you tryed anything? Do you have part of code? We don't write code for other we _help_

Comment: Instead reading Cell by cell just read and fill into dataset. By this way you may avoid looping and the Error too

Comment: public object verify(object k)
        {
            try
            {
                if (range.Cells[rCnt, 3] == null)
                {
                  return  range.Cells[rCnt, 3].value="null";
                }
            }
        catch
            {
                return k;
        }
        
        }

Comment: @user2265801 - Update your question code in comments is basically unreadable.